# How to change the text direction of the xtick labels in matplotlib so that it is stacked vertically?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For example, I have a barplot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
h = [10,20,30]
x = [1,2,3]
xticks = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']
plt.bar(x, height = h, tick_label = xticks)
```

similar to this

[Barplot with horizontal xtick label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgqYM.png)

But I want to rotate/stack the xtick labels so that the text direction are arranged vertically like this (wrap to multiple lines)

[Barplot with stacked xtick label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCZbN.png)

I want to do this because one could read the text vertically without rotating the direction of the characters, otherwise one would have to rotate the head to read the text (especially useful for Chinese characters).

In MS PowerPoint I could use "Stack" to [set the text direction](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/set-text-direction-and-position-in-a-shape-or-text-box-64d887b8-91b2-4293-8104-9d4a92a10fc8?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us), but how can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to modify the text of the label to put returns between every character:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
h = [10,20,30]
x = [1,2,3]
xticks = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']
xticks_stacked = ['\n'.join(x) for x in xticks]
plt.bar(x, height = h, tick_label = xticks_stacked)
```

[image]

Note: to save an image of this figure without cutting off the label text, you can use:

```
plt.savefig('filename.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```